# WCF Data Service template with Visual Studio 2013 preview

Tags: visual-studio-2012, odata, visual-studio-templates, visual-studio-2013

A day ago I reformatted my computer and installed Windows 8.1 and then Visual Studio 2013 Preview.

I was very VERY happy with all the changes, but I encountered one thing that's missing from 2012 version:
WCF Data Service template

Thing is that not only the template is missing, but the one that works with 2012 is not compatible with 2013 Preview even when I add template package manualy and change the assembly version in .vstemplate file.

Am I missing something and this is not enough:

```
<Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.ServicesWizard, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
```

Change version from 11.0.0.0 to 12.0.0.0 like this:

```
<Assembly>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.ServicesWizard, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
```

I need to set up OData service and without the template - it would be pain..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update: you can find the 5.6 tools installer here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39373]**

Original response:

The WCF Data Services team just announced an alpha release of the installer that supports Visual Studio 2013. Right now (July 1, 2013), the download isn't actually up yet, but it should be available soon. The [announcement post here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/06/28/wcf-data-services-5-6-0-alpha.aspx) will be updated when the download is ready.

Comment: Thanks... Would be nice, if they were faster :))

Comment: Ha, ok. I got a little worried, so I'm happy to hear this still works :)

Comment: Ok, I've run the installer and I still have no idea where to find the "WCF Data Service".  It is not available as a template.