# WCF Data Service Template is Missing

Tags: wcf, dataservice

I am using VS 2013 and have created an EntityFramework data model project.  Now, I need to create a WCF data service to access the data model.  I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393623/wcf-data-service-template-with-visual-studio-2013-preview) and have installed the referenced file.  However, I still do not see a way to create a WCF Data Service.  Installing this package did not add anything to my templates.  How do I use it?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.  I had to install [another package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider/1.0.0-alpha2).